# Want to select all the columns of the table while clubbing similar column value

Tags: mysql, sql

[My Table : Book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcYnL.jpg)

Table Name : Book.
The Last Column(NoOfBooksPerCourse) is what I to be computed along with fetching all the other columns

```
|BookID  | Title  | Publisher   | Author   | CourseID    | NoOfBooksPerCourse   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1   |   Book1|   Publisher1|  Author1 |     1       |  2         
|    2   |   Book2|   Publisher2|  Author2 |     1       |  2        
|    3   |   Book3|   Publisher3|  Author3 |     2       |  1         
|    4   |   Book1|   Publisher4|  Author4 |     3       |  1
```

I have this table and I want to select all the cloumns and also compute NoOfBooksPerCourse column(in MySql). Any suggestions?

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT Title, Publisher, Author, COUNT( CourseID ) AS NoOfBooksPerCourse
FROM Book
GROUP BY (
CourseID
)
```

But it does not select all of the rows in the table(added as attachment link), it only selects the first row of each CourseID.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results *in the question* (not using links).  It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I have just added the query I am using..

Comment: My question specifically asked for data.  Your query is clearly not working, so it doesn't do a very good job of explaining what you *want* to do.

Comment: I added my sample table data..hope this helps..

Comment: What do you want from result? Show us result data.

Comment: I am a newbie on stackoverflow, so it's taking a lot of time for me to edit my table format :-) . Hope this edit helps.

Answer (score 0):

To select everything from `Book` you can use `SELECT *`. Any extra counts can be added as inline select statements:

```
SELECT b1.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Book b2 WHERE b2.CourseID = b1.CourseID) As NoOfBooksPerCourse
FROM Book b1
```